# Is there a way to organize Postgres Functions (using pgAdmin)?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using pgAdmin 4.23, PostgreSQL 12.3 for Windows

Looks like all functions are dumped into one "folder".  I installed the uuid and tablefunc extensions and they get tossed in with my own user defined functions.  At least the 10 uuid ones are all prefixed with "uuid_".  The 11 tablefunc ones all start with "connectby", "crosstab"*, "normal_rand".

I did prefix my own functions so those at least grouped together.  But as this thing grows and I add extensions, I'm concerned that maintenance will become more difficult.  Is there some sort of sub-foldering option I am missing, or is naming convention the normal approach for organization?  Looks like stored procs would work the same way.

Would also be nice to be able to filter the Functions based on the names.  I see the Search Objects popup, but it isn't as useful as a filter.

Comment: Use schemas (aka namespaces)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we debated this.  Considered making a schema specifically to house all installed extensions, for example.  Would this be proper design?  Any foreseeable difficulties?  Initially we decided that since schemas were intended for domain organization (not just functions and procs, also includes tables, views, etc...), it would be awkward to use them for this purpose.

Comment: A schema has no inherent "intention". It's a namespace, nothing more nothing less. How you use it is completely up to you. If you choose to put all functions into one schema then there is nothing wrong with it. If you decide to install every extension in their own schema there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Well dang, right there in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-schemas.html
"Third-party applications can be put into separate schemas so they do not collide with the names of other objects."
Guess I should have rtfm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this here in case it helps for future searches...

Per @horse_with_no_name's suggestion above, and the official documentation I went with a separate schema for my third-party stuff.  Here is a bit from conversation with the other db people in our company:

> I didn't want third party extensions (like uuid-ossp for Guids)
> installed in my public schema since that is where we keep all of our
> user defined functions specific to that database.  When I originally
> installed the extension I put it into the public schema, then just
> transferred it to a schema named extfunc.  Then we have a table named
> usr that references extfunc.uuid_generate_v4() in one of the column
> constraints.  Everything works as expected.
>
> However, when I try to backup our Dev db and restore to QA, the
> pg_dump and pg_restore tasks do not handle it properly.  The restore
> would error and not create the usr table.  The extension was not being
> properly restored to extfunc, which prevented the usr table from being
> created.
>
> The solution is to create the extension in the desired schema from the
> start.  Do not create it and try and move it to the destination
> schema.  Backup/restore now work as expected.

Comment: You _can_ move an extension to a different schema (if the extension allows it) using `alter extension` - you can't do that by renaming the individual functions

Answer (score 1):

To filter functions based on their names you can use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.find_function(fname text DEFAULT NULL::text)
 RETURNS TABLE(routine_name text, routine_schema text, return_type text)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
    select routine_name, routine_schema, data_type 
    from information_schema.routines 
    where specific_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    and case when fname is null then true else routine_name ~* fname end
    order by routine_name;
$function$;
```

Here is an example - find all functions that have "test" in their name:

```
select * from find_function('test');
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| routine_name                | routine_schema | return_type |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| clear_web_tests             | datavato       | void        |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| etl_generic_tests           | webaccess      | text        |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| fill_web_tests              | datavato       | void        |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| pan_arguments_test          | helpers        | jsonb       |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| test_bizday                 | public         | boolean     |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| test_checkdigits            | public         | boolean     |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+  
| test_jasper_dynamic_columns | scratch        | record      |
+-----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: clever.  I'd much rather the tooling integrate with the object organization, but pgAdmin being a web page does make a lot of intricate customization harder than something like a traditional windows .exe (I come from using SSMS).

Comment: Give DBeaver (https://dbeaver.io/) a try. I hope that you will like it.

Comment: That was the other mgmt app I have.  It has a nice ER diagramming tool.